# Did anyone in Zeno time, use the idea of discrete space/time to propose a solution to his paradoxes?

Tags: aristotle, epicurus, zeno-of-elea

Zeno famously stated a number of paradoxes of space, time & motion to argue for parmenides unity & changelessness of being.

Infinite divisiblity of space & time seemed to be a commonly held view then (Aristotle distinguishes between infinite extent and infinite divisiblity), did anyone propose resolving his paradoxes by arguing against this?

I'm thinking of how Epicurus gave his atoms, indivisible matter further structure of minima which he proposed as an indivisible extent.

Comment: If we want to be simple Aristotle did it.

Answer (score 6):

If they did, it wouldn't have helped.

As [Robert Brumbaugh](http://archive.org/details/philosophersofgr002376mbp) pointed out, Zeno constructed four different paradoxes: one that covers continuous time and discrete space, on that covers continuous space and discrete time, one that covers continuous time and space, and one that covers discrete time and space.

Comment: See also: http://www.iep.utm.edu/zeno-par/